# Passing multiple values in a checkbox using PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is it possible to pass multiple values with a checkbox submit. I need to pass the `value` and the `data-export` to the insert statement in php? Is it possible in PHP?

**Example (HTML):**

```
<input type="checkbox" data-export="<?= $list1['export_charges']; ?>"  name="chk_export[exportinr]"  value="<?= $list1['export_charges_inr']; ?>">
```

**In PHP:**

```
 $exportinr = $_POST['chk_export']['exportinr'];
```

Comment: Not 100% clear what you are asking - are you saying you have multiple checkboxes as part of a group, and you want to pass all the values through?

Comment: You could come up with a solution with jQuery appending the data attribute, right out of the box only the value is passed alogn with the name.

Comment: I have a checkbox, if checked i need to pass the values to the next page. Now iam passing a value with value=' ' attribute. I need to pass one more variable with the checkbox. Am i clear?

Comment: @Jan, only jquery is the option? Never worked on jquery.

Comment: @SanjuMenon No, this is not the only option but makes it a lot easier.

Comment: pass two variable value in value by separator and use this two value in javascript by exploding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution for it

```
<input type='checkbox' value='.$list1['export_charges_inr'].' name="chk_export[]" />
<input type='checkbox' value='.$list1['export_charges'].' name="chk_export[]" />
```

Php code to get the values

```
$numb = count($chk_export);
for($i=0;$i<=($numb - 1);$i++){
    echo $chk_export[$i];
}
```

One more solution is

```
<input type="checkbox" value="'.$list1['export_charges'].':'.$list1['export_charges_inr'].'" name="chk_export" />
```

In php

```
$pieces = explode(":", $_POST['chk_export']);
echo $pieces[0];
echo $pieces[1];
```

Comment: But how can i pass one more value to the checkbox here? Example i need to pass '.$list1['export_charges'].' and '.$list1['export_charges_inr'] with the checkbox.

Comment: You can do it using the second solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a delimiter like so:

```
<input value="value#data-export-value" name="somefield">
```

Then in PHP:

```
list($value, $dataexport) = explode("#", $_POST["somefield"]);
// $value and $dataexport will hold the appropriate values
```

Or try it with a library, e.g. jQuery:

```
$("#formName").on('submit', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var fieldvalue = $("#somefield").val();
    var fielddata = $("#somefield").data('export');
    var data = {fieldvalue: fieldvalue, fielddata: fielddata};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data
    });
});
```

In PHP, you will have access to fieldvalue & fielddata like so:

```
$fieldvalue = $_POST["fieldvalue"];
```

If you have never worked with jQuery before, better use the delimiter solution.

Comment: Yes i will try the explode solution suggested by you.

Answer (score 0):

I think with current code, it will pass only one value,

```
name="chk_export[exportinr]"
```

change it like this

```
name="chk_export[exportinr][]"
```

or

```
name="chk_export[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

data-* attributes are designed to be handled by client side code.

If you want to submit two or more values you can have other solutions like:

1. Use hidden input fields to hold the other values.
2. use a custom made pattern of your values and post them i.e

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk_export" value='.$list1['export_charges'].'-'.$list1['export_charges_inr'].'>
   ```

and on the PHP side receive the post value and explode it at '**-**'

```
    $arr = explode("-", $_POST["chk_export"]);
```

Comment: @ Junaid. This is my checkbox code. <input type="checkbox" name="chk_export[exportinr]"  value='.$list1['export_charges_inr'].',> How will i add a hidden field to this check box and get a  value?

Comment: @SanjuMenon Add hidden input fields parallel to checkbox input, so that form can carry them with it when POST

Comment: Can u give me a small example on how to how to explode the above said code?

Answer (score 0):

Your input tag should be like this

```
<input type="checkbox" data-export='.$list1['export_charges'].' name="chk_export[exportinr][]"  value='.$list1['export_charges_inr'].'>
```

Now to get value of each check box you have to use php for loop something like this:

$N = count($_POST['chk_export[exportinr][]']);

```
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
  echo($_POST['chk_export[exportinr][$i]']);
}
```

Comment: But how will i process the data-export values there?

Comment: You will have to get it by using 

`$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');  /***insert it outside loop ***/`

`$attr = $a->item($i)->getAttribute('target');  /***insert it inside loop ***/`

Hope this wel help you